# sSearch and fnServerParams, DataTables.net

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to set up some search box / datepickers up outside of the main table, i've done some searching and read that i need to pass my values in fnServerParams with a custom value. So, i do this:

```
 "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                    aoData.push({
                        "name": "iArchiveYears", "value":  $("#ddYears :selected").text()}
                       , { "name": "iMsgType", "value": $('#msgTypeSearch').val() }
                        )
                },
```

Which, when viewed in firebug appear fine as can be seen below:

[image: firebug output]

I'm using a click function combined with fnFilter to try and filter bsaed on a specific value for a specific columns, which looks like this :

```
$('#msgTypeSearch').keyup(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       oMsgDateDetail.fnFilter(this.value, 4, false, false, false, true);
   });
```

for some reason this isnt filtering at all and i note that the value for the search box appears in sSearch4 - do i therefore need to specifiy fnServerParams at all? i'm not sure, as the date (2011) doesnt appear in the sSearch fields.

Is it possible to filter using fnFilter at all??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oMsgDateDetail.fnFilter(this.value, XX, false, false, false, true);
   });`

Send a request to the server and `sSearch_XX` = the value

`oMsgDateDetail.fnFilter(this.value);
   });`

Send a request to the server and `sSearch` = the value

In server-side, you need to search and send all records.

`fnFilter` doesn't filter when `bServer-side` = true.
When `bServer-side` = false. It search in your local data

Comment: so in this instance then, i don't need the server param IMsgType as i can access it via the sSearch_4 variable. Good stuff. Enjoying these points Olivier? +1 for me perhaps :-)